# Make Target's Build Products Path in Xcode dependent on Current Scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, configuration, build

I have an Xcode Project with three targets:

1. A Mac app to be distributed on the Mac App Store
2. The same Mac app, but to be distributed as a demo version on my
       website
3. A login helper app that is a target dependency for the first two
       targets

The login helper app is copied on build to the target of the current scheme (let's say the first target), which has a build path of

> $(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)

When I change the scheme to the second target (the demo), I'd like for the build products path of the third target to be the same, except with _Demo attached to it. *Basically, the third target's build path should always be the same as the current scheme's target (either target one or two).*

Currently, I do it manually before building, but that's tedious.

Is there no way to make the Per-configuration Build Products Path (and the Per-configuration Intermediate Build Files Path, etc) dependent on the current target?

So when I select the first target, no _Demo gets attached to the path, when I select the second target, _Demo does get attached to the path.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want the login helper’s building to be aware of which “parent target” it’s being built in. Not sure if that’s possible.

What I’d do in this case, is add a separate “Copy” build step into targets 1 and 2. It sounds like copy is currently a part of building target 3, but it works better if it’s part of building targets 1 and 2.

I have a very similar situation with a command-line helper in one of my tools. Here’s the relevant part of my build settings.

[image]

Comment: Agreed, OP is just making life hard. It's easier to build target 3 into its normal destination, then have builds 1 and 2 copy it from there to wherever they need it to be.

Comment: This works if Target 1 and Target 2 are built into the same build folder. However, if I change Target 2's build folder, Target 3 is looked for in THAT build folder and not in its own and thus doesn't build anymore. But for now, I guess I'll build them all in the same folder and be done with it.

Comment: This shouldn’t have anything to do with Target 1 and 2 build folders. I’m using a similar configuration myself and added an example screenshot.